# Adding and replacing Fragments , is not working as expected in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was trying out android fragments, and i could not understand this; please help

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) !=null) {
            if(savedInstanceState!=null){
                return ;
            }
            ArticleFragment first_fragment = new ArticleFragment();
            HeadlineFragment second_fragment = new HeadlineFragment();
            first_fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            second_fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
            FragmentTransaction manager=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            manager.add(R.id.fragment_container, first_fragment,"first");
            manager.add(R.id.yo, second_fragment,"second");
            manager.commit();
        }
    }
```

now i want to remove second_fragment at a button press and replace it with another. So i tried this

```
if(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("second")!=null) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"found");
                    abc newFragment = new abc();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    transaction.remove(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("second"));
                    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,newFragment,"third");
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
                }
```

but when i press that button again and again, the if condition passes.
What is wrong here?

Comment: where you have the problem  ?  in first method or second ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't Do removing and adding. Simply Replace second fragment with the new one. You will be done.

Comment: u mean like this?
transaction.replace(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("second").getId(), newFragment, "third");

Comment: transaction.replace(R.id.yo,newFragment);  Check the null not condition on fragment.

Comment: i am still getting same problem.